# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service Asp .net core 6 web api clean architecture

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, clean-architecture

I'm working on clean architecture with  ASP .net 6  core web api and I'm about testing simple crud ( get method ) .
I've found this error :
[image: error]
I have integrated repository pattern in persistence layer and folder for repositories' interfaces like in this screenshot + DbContext there  :

[image: persistence layer]

This code of Irepository:

```
using Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Domain.Interfaces.IRepositories
{
    public interface ISPRepository
    {
        Task<List<SP>> GetByIdsAsync(int ids);

        Task<List<SP>> GetAllAsync();
    }
}
```

This code of repository :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Domain.Entities;
using Domain.Interfaces.IRepositories;
using Persistence.DBContext;


 namespace Persistence.Repositories
{
    public  class SPRepository: ISPRepository
    {
        private readonly SPContext _context;
        
        // method to get SP by id
        public async Task<List<SP>> GetByIdsAsync(int ids)
        {
            return await this._context
                .SPs
                .Where(x => x.SPId==ids).ToListAsync();
        }
        //method to get SP
        public async Task<List<SP>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await this._context
                .SPs
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Application layer :
[image: application layer]

This is the service's interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SP.Domain.Entities;
namespace SP.Application.SP.Queries.Iservices
{
    public interface IGetSPService
    {
        Task<List<SP>> GetSPByIdAsync(int SPId);
        Task<List<SP>> GetAllAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the service's :

```
using SP.Domain.Interfaces.IRepositories;
using SP.Domain.Entities;
using SP.Application.SP.Queries.Iservices;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SP.Application.SP.Queries.Services
{
    public  class GetSPService: IGetSPService
    {
        private readonly ISPRepository  _SPRepository;

        public GetSPService(ISPRepository SPRepository)
        {
            _SPRepository = SPRepository;
        }
        
        public async Task<List<SP>> GetSPByIdAsync(int SPId)
        {
            return await _SPRepository.GetByIdsAsync(SPId);
        }
        public async Task<List<SP>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _SPRepository.GetAllAsync();
        }
       
    }
}
```

This server.api layer:
[image: api.server]

This the controller code:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SP.Application.SP.Queries.Iservices;
using SP.Domain.Entities;
using System.Xml;

namespace SP.Api.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]

    public class SPController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IGetSPService _service;
        public SPController(IGetSPService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<SP>>> GetSPById(int  id)
        {
            var entity = await _service.GetSPByIdAsync(id);

            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return entity;
        }
    }
}
```

This is program.cs :

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SP.Persistence.DBContext;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();*/


var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
                
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
// this line has removed "localhost not found" 
app.UsePathBase("/SP.Api.Server");


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: You have to use a dependency injection. I can not see any code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> Unable to resolve service for type IGetService While attempting to
> Active SPController

indicates when it try to create the instance of `SPController` ,it could not find the service type of `IGetService` which is a parameter in the constructor of SPController in container(IServiceProvider)

to solve the error, you have to regist the service in Program.cs as below:

```
builder.Service.AddScoped<IGetService,GetService>
```

And for the parameter type of ISPRepository in the constructor of GetSPService,you also have to add this line

```
builder.Service.AddScoped<ISPRepository,SPRepository>
```

And inject the dbcontext into SPRepository as below

```
public  class SPRepository: ISPRepository
    {
        private readonly SPContext _context;
        

       public   SPRepository(SPContext context)
       {
         _context=context;
        }
        // method to get SP by id
        public async Task<List<SP>> GetByIdsAsync(int ids)
        {
            return await this._context
                .SPs
                .Where(x => x.SPId==ids).ToListAsync();
        }
        //method to get SP
        public async Task<List<SP>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await this._context
                .SPs
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Regist the Dbcontext:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SPContext>(......)
```

For more details, you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for dependency injection in Asp.net core and this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)  for DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core

Comment: Hello @Rukai , I had this issue : System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'
Actually for connectionstring , I have added it by Scaffold cli , and I don't have it in appsettings , so, by adding it to appsettings , can something change ?

Comment: If you are reading your connction string with IConfiguration make sure you have a section in your appsetting as this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-generated-database-connection-string

Comment: Also make sure the name of dbcontext in appsettings.json  is same with your dbcontext class,if you still have problem,please update the related codes

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a dependency injection. I can not see any code at all. For example\

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SPContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And it is another example  to add dbcontext to your repository

```
public  class SPRepository: ISPRepository
{
  private readonly SPContext _context;

public   SPRepository(SPContext context)
{
   _context=context;
}
....
}
```

and there are a lot of bugs like above